# vs code prettier - adds new line after @Input() decorator in angular

Tags: visual-studio-code, formatting, prettier

I've been using `prettier` for near 2 years now to format my `angular` code. Starting last week `prettier` starts to insert a new line behind all `angular` statements with decorators like `@Input()`, `@Output()`, `@ViewChild()`,..

resulting in something like

```
@Input()
property1

@Output()
emitter
```

which doubles the line count and doesn't add to readability.

My `prettier` settings are:

```
  "editor.tabSize": 2,
  "prettier.singleQuote": true,
  "prettier.tabWidth": 2,
  "prettier.useTabs": false,
  "prettier.semi": true,
  "prettier.printWidth": 120,
  "prettier.eslintIntegration": true,
```

Event when I reset to default settings, this new line thing still occurs.
Does anybody has suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the following related open feature request:
https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/1974

It looks like, for now, they do not have an option to change the behaviour...

According to Angular style guideline, it should be on one line:
https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#decorate-input-and-output-properties

Comment: Thats really strange, for at least the past year i've been using prettier and it didn't format them into 2 lines...

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio code prettier adds a new line to every parameter in the statement when the Print width option is a very small number eg: 80.

Please follow the steps mentioned below to overcome this problem in code formatting:

1. In Visual Studio code go to File -> Preferences -> Settings
2. Type Prettier in the search bar.
3. Navigate to the option 
   Prettier: Print Width
   Fit code within this line limit
4. Modify the width option as per your need, I made it to 800 to get back everything in 
   the same line.
5. Also, check the js same line tag option as shown the screenshot below.

Thanks hope this helps...

[image: Screenshot for reference]

[image: Sameline bracket]